# Object has no method 'match' jQuery .get()

Tags: jquery, match

I'm using .get() to get some info on a page, where I will then use the data to find the matching text, and display it.

```
$.get('http://website.com', function(data) {
    result = $(data).match(/Status(.*?)<br>/);
    console.log(result);
});
```

I am unable to match the data (I also tried without the jQuery, so the 'string' was just data), but same result.
I tried toString(), innerHTML and so on, but it didn't work.

I tried searching for answers, but I can't seem to know it. .html() doesn't work neither.

What I'm trying to find:

```
<strong>Status:</strong>
"some text"
<p>Test</p>
<br>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked in the console what data contains?

Comment: What is supposed to be in the `data` argument?  We need to know that in order to advise what the proper code would be.  jQuery objects don't have a `.match()` method which is what your current code is trying to do.

Comment: Data contains the .get() data. Pretty normal. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the datatype as `text` and try

```
$.get('http://website.com', function(data) {
    result = data.match(/Status(.*?)<br>/);
    console.log(result);
}, 'text');
```

Comment: Returned null for me.

Comment: can you do a `console.log(data)`

Comment: Sure. It will give me the whole source of the .get() page. So the source of website.com in this example.

Comment: @Snorlax which means the regex passed is not matching anything in the passed data ex: `'asf'.match(/\d/)` returns null

Comment: Right, so it's my regex which is bad?

Comment: @Snorlax looks like it

Comment: Right okay. Thanks. I've been getting null a lot, so I guess that my regex was just wrong. Check the edit I made in first post. When I try **data.match(/<strong>Status:<\/strong>(.*?)<br>/);** it'll return null. Can you tell me why it won't work? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Snorlax can you share a sample html

Comment: @Snorlax whether your html has a content like `<strong>Status:<\/strong>ddd<br>`